Download Folder Configuration in Selenium Not Working
even though the configuration seems to be right the custom download folder is not working. Could you please help me?
gecko_driver_path = 'C:/Users/X/Documents/CODE_PYTHON/project1/geckodriver.exe'

options = Options()
service = Service(gecko_driver_path)

datafolder = 'C:/Users/X/Documents/CODE_PYTHON/project1/data'
options.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)  # 2 means a custom download folder
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", datafolder)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xlsx")
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

